# Sometimes sweet, but sometimes not so much. What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Sometimes with treasure inside and sometimes without.
>
> Sometimes written with initials, but sometimes spelled out.
>
> Sometimes small and colorful and sometimes large and white.
>
> Sometimes you don't want to eat me, but sometimes you might.
>
> Sometimes I can be found in a pantry on a shelf, but if not you just might lose yourself.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> M&M/Eminem?

Sometimes with treasure inside and sometimes without.

> Peanut M&M's have "treasure inside" but Eminem the rapper does not.

Sometimes written with initials, but sometimes spelled out.

> M&M is witten with initials, Eminem is spelt out.

Sometimes small and colorful and sometimes large and white.

> M&Ms are small and colourful, but Eminem is tall and has white skin.

Sometimes you don't want to eat me, but sometimes you might.

> People don't want to eat Eminem, but they might want to eat M&Ms

Sometimes I can be found in a pantry on a shelf, but if not you just might lose yourself.

> M&Ms can be found on a shelf, and Lose Yourself is a song by Eminem

**Title:**

Sometimes sweet, but sometimes not so much

> M&Ms are sweet, but Eminem is not so much...

Comment: Eminem not so much... - Understatement of the millenia

Answer (score 3):

Another Answer

> Kisses

Sometimes sweet, but sometimes not so much

> Chocolate Kisses or Just Kisses

Sometimes with treasure inside and sometimes without.

> Stuffed chocolate Kisses or just Kisses

Sometimes written with initials, but sometimes spelled out.

> Brand written with initial or spelled Kisses

Sometimes small and colorful and sometimes large and white.

> small colored chocolate kisses or Large white kissing ball

Sometimes you don't want to eat me, but sometimes you might.

> You don't want to eat chocolate kisses and sometimes you kiss

Sometimes I can be found in a pantry on a shelf, but if not you just might lose yourself.

> Boxes on shelf (chocolate kisses pantry) or you lose yourself in kissing

Answer

> Chocolate

Sometimes sweet, but sometimes not so much

> Milk chocolate or Bitter chocolate

Sometimes with treasure inside and sometimes without.

> Stuffed chocolate or just plain

Sometimes written with initials, but sometimes spelled out.

> Brand written with initial or spelled

Sometimes small and colorful and sometimes large and white.

> small colored chocolate or Large white bar chocolate

Sometimes you don't want to eat me, but sometimes you might.

> You are on diet or diabetic and sometimes you need chocolate

Sometimes I can be found in a pantry on a shelf, but if not you just might lose yourself.

> Boxes on shelf (chocolate pantry) or you lose yourself in chocolate

Comment: You're on the right track. There is a homonym that could help you out.

Comment: @Grumpyllama59 Homo*nym* or homo*phone* (or homograph)? https://www.spellingcity.com/homophones-and-homonyms.html

Comment: My bad. I meant homophone.

Comment: M&M (Eminem)? He's a white guy who is considerably larger than the candy, and has a song called "Lose Yourself." My friend is the one who realized that "Lose Yourself" is a song, after he heard me mentioning this puzzle, so credit goes to him :)

Comment: Put it up as an answer and you got it!

Comment: Oops, didn't realise @RedOctopus had already commented before I posted my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A Marble?

Sometimes with treasure inside and sometimes without.

> I believe there are Geodes made of marble

Sometimes written with initials, but sometimes spelled out.

> Could be referring to monograms

Sometimes small and colorful and sometimes large and white.

> Small colorful marbles are usually glass, but marble is also a white stone, often large and carved.

Sometimes you don't want to eat me, but sometimes you might.

> Marbling of meat is a delicious distribution of fat

Sometimes I can be found in a pantry on a shelf, but if not you just might lose yourself.

> losing ones marbles is an idiom for losing one's mind

The title could be referring to

> Marble Cake

Comment: Good guess, but no

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Medication?

Sometimes sweet, but sometimes not so much.

> Some medication is sugar-coated, and there also exist sugar pills.

Sometimes with treasure inside and sometimes without.

> A bit foggy on this one--perhaps this refers to pills with a casing, where the medication is on the inside?

Sometimes written with initials, but sometimes spelled out.

> Tablets generally have some initials or the name of the drug on them.

Sometimes small and colorful and sometimes large and white.

> Medication comes in many different colors and shapes, and are often white.

Sometimes you don't want to eat me, but sometimes you might.

> Kids (and sometimes adults) generally find taking medication to be a chore, but sometimes you really need an aspirin.

Sometimes I can be found in a pantry on a shelf, but if not you just might lose yourself.

> Some people store their medication in the pantry, and if you lose medication for a serious disease, that could be dangerous (mentally or physically).

Comment: Good guess, but no